# How to cast rust bitflags entries into int

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

How to use [bitflag](https://docs.rs/bitflags/latest/bitflags/) entries as int. For eaxmple:

```
bitflags! {
    struct Flags: u8 {
        const NONE = 1;
        const SOME = 2;
    }
}
```

Now if I want to compare Flags::SOME == 2, how to cast the Flags::SOME to u8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just discovered it can be done using 'bits()':

```
Flags::SOME.bits() == 2
```